# I have two JTables I need to using Up/Down Arrow Key to Move in a master JTable and get the Data in detail JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have  two `JTable` components (master table (`tableA`) and detail table (`tableB`)) I need to using Up/Down Arrow Key to Move in a master table and get the Data in detail table.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
private void jTable1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        MoveMasterdetail();
    }
}   

private static final String UP = "UP";
private static final String DOWN = "DOWN";    
public void MoveMasterdetail() {
      int condition = jTable1.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = jTable1.getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = jTable1.getActionMap();

      inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), UP);
      actionMap.put(UP, new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             fetchDetail(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString().trim());
         }
      });

      inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), DOWN);
      actionMap.put(DOWN, new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             fetchDetail(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString().trim());

         }
      });

   }

    public void fetchDetail(String autonationalno) {
    try {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatementSelect = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            int i = 0;
            //inner join or outer join
            String sql =
            "select * from tableB";

            preparedStatementSelect = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = preparedStatementSelect.executeQuery();
            jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Please provide solution to this.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) *"Please provide solution to this."* Please provide a (clear, specific) question.

Comment: You want a `SelectionListener` to monitor the change of the selection in the first table so you can update the second

Comment: I need when i press arrow key(up and down) in the master table then the data change on detail table depand on value on value of jtable1

Comment: *"I need.."* Yes, we get that. But it seems you are not understanding our advice. Where is the MCVE / SSCCE? Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @Omar Ah, yes, did you look at the `ListSelectionListener`? Did you do any research into it's functionality and what it does?

Answer (score 0):

> I need when i press arrow key(up and down)...

What if the user wants the details of the last row of the table?

They should NOT need to scroll through the entire table just to see the details of the last row, especially when you do a database query for the detail data. The user should be able to use the mouse or the keyboard to select the row they want the details for.

That is why the `ListSelectionListener` is the better solution. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for a working example to get you started.

Comment: @Omarm glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @Omar, What do you mean the problem is not solved. You have been given a link to a tutorial that contains working examples. You can also search the forum for other examples that use a ListSelectionListener. We are not here to write the code for you. You have all the information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Omar, once again,  glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer, by clicking on the checkmark, so people know the problem has been solved.